# SQL: select data before first occurence of a certain value

Tags: sql, pyspark

For example, I have order data come from customers, like this

```
test = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 1, "2018-06-03"),
    (1, 1, 1, "2018-06-04"),
    (2, 1, 3, "2018-06-04"),
    (3, 1, 2, "2018-06-05"),
    (4, 1, 1, "2018-06-06"),
    (5, 2, 3, "2018-06-01"),
    (6, 2, 1, "2018-06-01"),
    (7, 3, 1, "2018-06-02"),
    (8, 3, 1, "2018-06-02"),
    (9, 3, 1, "2018-06-05")
])\
  .toDF("order_id", "customer_id", "order_status", "created_at")
test.show()
```

[image]

Each order has its own status, `1` means newly created but not finished, `3` means it's payed and finished.

Now, I want to do analysis for order comes from

- new customers (who has not made purchase before)
- old customers (who has finished purchase before)

so I want to add a feature to the above the data, turn into like this

[image]

The logic is for every customer, every order created before first order with status `3` (include itself) is counted as come from `new customer`, and every order after that is counted as `old customer`.

Or put it into another way, **select the data before the first occurance of value 3 (for each customer's order, sort by date asc)**

How can I do this, in SQL?

I searched around but didn't find good solution. If in Python, I think maybe I'll simply do some loop to get the values.

Comment: You could try using where exists or not exists to join to the same table on matching customer id and a theta join (order_id < order_id).

Answer (score 0):

This is tested for SQLite:

```
SELECT order_id, customer_id, order_status, created_at, 
CASE
     WHEN order_id > (SELECT MIN(order_id) FROM orders WHERE customer_id = o.customer_id AND order_status = 3) THEN 'old'
     ELSE 'new'  
END AS customer_status
FROM orders o
```

Comment: Why it uses `order_id`?

Comment: Take for example the 2 rows for `customer_id=2`, they both have  `created_at=2018-06-01`. So there is no *before* or *after* for these 2 rows if we compare them based on `created_at`. If I replace in my code `order_id` with `created_at` then both these rows will give `new`. I think that it's safer to use the `order_id` unless it is not related to the date of the placement of the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions in Spark:

```
select t.*,
       (case when created_at > min(case when status = 3 then created_at end) over (partition by customer_id)
             then 'old'
             else 'new'
        end) as customer_status
from test t;
```

Note that this assigns "new" to customers with no order with status "3".

You can also write this using `join` and `group by`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t3.customer_status, 'old') as customer_status
from test t left join
     (select t.customer_id, min(created_at) as min_created_at,
             'new' as customer_status
      from t
      where status = 3
      group by t.customer_id
     ) t3
     on t.customer_id = t3.customer_id and
        t.created_at <= t3.min_created_at;
```